# Iphython Viewer crash when I view some model

Tags: python, python-2.7, ipython

i don't know why but when I'm showing some model on ipython, the viewer crash and send to me an error like XgeModule whas shut down. Why?

This is the code:

```
def CIRCLE(r):
  dom = INTERVALS(2*PI)(50)
  def circ(p):
    return ([r*COS(p[0]),r*SIN(p[0])])
  return SOLIDIFY(MAP(circ)(dom))

vetro = COLOR([1,1,0,0.7])(CIRCLE(0.4))

Dom1D = INTERVALS(1)(60)
Dom2D = PROD([Dom1D,Dom1D])

profile = BEZIER(S1)([[0,0,0],[0.4,0,0],[0.4,0,0.4]])

rot_domain = PROD([INTERVALS(1)(60),INTERVALS(2*PI)(60)])
mapping = ROTATIONALSURFACE(profile)
closing = COLOR(BLACK)(MAP(mapping)(rot_domain))

fanale = R([2,3])(PI/2)(S([1,2,3])([2.5,2.5,2.5])(STRUCT([T([3])([0.4])vetro),closing])))

DRAW(fanale)
```

And this is the error on Ubuntu Terminal:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadWindow (invalid Window parameter)
  Major opcode of failed request:  40 (X_TranslateCoords)
  Resource id in failed request:  0x3c00011
  Serial number of failed request:  606
  Current serial number in output stream:  606
XgeModule::shutdown
```

Comment: You have to provide more details, for example your code

Comment: added! but it not depend from the code because I have the same error for various code

Comment: and what is the library from which you import MAP,COS and all these other stuff ?

Comment: It's not an IPython problem - IPython doesn't do anything with X. You need to look at whatever library or framework you're doing the drawing with.